# localized country names in asp.net/C# missing countries

Tags: asp.net

I am using following code to show localized country names ( name of the country in its language), but most of the countries are missing like Zimbabwe:

```
Dictionary<string, string> objDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                foreach (CultureInfo ObjCultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
                {
                    RegionInfo objRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(ObjCultureInfo.Name);
                    if (!objDic.ContainsValue(objRegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower()))
                    {
                        objDic.Add(objRegionInfo.NativeName, objRegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower());
                    }
                }

                var obj = objDic.OrderBy(p => p.Key);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in obj)
                {
                    cmbCountry.Items.Add(new ListItem(val.Key, val.Value.ToUpper()));
                }
```

It shows 127 countries out of 245, Please suggest me solution to this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change this line:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
```

To this:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
```

That will feach all the cultures. If you see msdn:

> CultureTypes.AllCultures , which returns all neutral and specific
>   cultures, cultures installed in the Windows operating system, and
>   custom cultures created by the user.
>
> CultureTypes.SpecificCultures , which returns all specific cultures.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx)

Comment: that gives the error:  The region name zh-CHS should not correspond to neutral culture; a specific culture name is required.
Parameter name: name